# jquery dataTables - how to add an edit and delete option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/5ooyertu/1/

Right now, the table is being populated properly via the server side, and my paging works.  But I'd like to add the ability to delete and or edit a row. I would like to add a column called "Actions" that has two  - one to an edit method... and the other to a delete method.

Prior to using dataTables, I had some JavaScript logic that would iterate through an array of records from an Ajax, call and populate a regular table with the data, and the appropriate hyper-links.

```
 for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].grp == 0) {
     tr.append("<a href='add.html?id=" + data[i].id + "&pid=" + data[i].pid + "&destination=" + data[i].destination + "&name=" + data[i].name.replace("'", "%27") + "'</a><button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>");
     tr.append("<button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' onclick='delete(" + data[i].id + "," + data[i].pid + ");'>Delete</button></td>")

 } else {
     tr.append("<a href='update_group.html?id=" + data[i].id + "&pid=" + data[i].pid + "&destination=" + data[i].destination + "&name=" + data[i].name.replace("'", "%27") + "'</a><button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>");
     tr.append("<button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' onclick='delete(" + data[i].id + "," + data[i].pid + ",true);'>Delete</button></td>")
  }
}
```

As you can see from the above code example, in my hyperlinks, I need to pass a few pieces of data from each row, either as a part of the query string (in the case of edits) or just pass them as parameters to another JavaScript function called "delete" that lives in the same file as this dataTable.  And it's conditional... meaning, the hyperlinks will change depending on whether grp is true / false.

I am wondering how I can change the logic that populates the dataTable to now include these two hyper-links?

I found this link: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5862/creating-an-action-column-for-icons-view-edit-delete# But the code didn't work for me and I think I read somewhere that the fnRender method is deprecated now.

If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT 1**

I tried to change my code to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected = [];
    $('#users').DataTable( {

        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
         aLengthMenu: [
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "-1"],
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "ajax": "/cgi-bin/test",
        "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
            if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        },
        "columns": 
        [    
                { "data": "id" ,"searchable":false},
                { "data": "name","searchable":true},    
                { "data": "pid", "searchable":true },    
                { "data": "destination", "searchable":true },
                {"mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return '<a href=add.html?id="'+row[0]+'">Edit</a>';}
                }
        ]
    } );
    
} );
```

Notice the call reference to render. I also added a new column to my table in my html code.  I do get a hyperlink!  But unfortunately, the link is incorrect.  row[0] returns "undefined".  Also, I still don't know how to change the hyperlink i create depending on the value of the field "destination".
So for example, I want to do something like this: (pseudocode)

```
if row[i].destination = 'Group' then
                    {"mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<a href=group.html?id="'+row[0]+'">Edit</a>';}
                    }
else
                    {"mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<a href=add.html?id="'+row[0]+'">Edit</a>';}
                    }
end
```

**EDIT 2**

This code seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected = [];
    $('#users').DataTable( {

        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
         aLengthMenu: [
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "-1"],
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "ajax": "/cgi-bin/test",
        "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
            if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        },
        "columns": 
        [    
                { "data": "id" ,"searchable":false},
                { "data": "name","searchable":true},    
                { "data": "pid", "searchable":true },    
                { "data": "destination", "searchable":true },
                {"mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return '<a href=add.html?id='+row.id+'>Edit</a>';}
                }
        ]
   });
```

Now I just need to figure out how I'm going to make it conditional.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you have an example assuming the following:

- Ajax population
- Data row is an array containing 4 columns
- Your data row contains the id on first column
- You don't display id on table so you hide it

It shouldn't be hard to adapt it to your needs. Check [`columns`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) usage

```
var datatablesOptions = {
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajaxSource": '[yourAjaxUrl]',
    "processing": true,
    "columns": [
        { bVisible = false }, // assume this is the id of the row, so don't show it
        null,
        null,
        null,
        /* EDIT */ {
            mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                return '<a class="table-edit" data-id="' + row[0] + '">EDIT</a>'
            }
        }
        /* DELETE */ {
            mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                return '<a class="table-delete" data-id="' + row[0] + '">DELETE</a>'
            }
        },              
     ]
};
$('#table').dataTable(datatablesOptions);
```

**EDIT**

In case you need to conditional render something different depending on `destination` you could do

```
mRender: function (data, type, row) {
    if (row.destination == "d1") {
        return '<a href="destination1?id=' + row.id + '">EDIT</a>'
    }else (row.destination == "d2"){
        return '<a href="destination2?id=' + row.id + '">EDIT</a>'
    } else {
        // some error telling that destination value is unexpected
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind showing me the mrender in conjunction with my jsfiddle code?  I'm just reading the reference you included about columns... but it's just not clear to me yet how to use your example.  Also how do I change the hyperlink target based on the value of row[0].destination ?  sorry for the many questions.

Comment: thanks.  But row[0] is returning a value of undefined.  and I need a conditional statement... I tried to explain in my Edit 1

Comment: Could you debug and check what `row` is? BTW: I made a change on my code to allow the possibility to perform delete / edit operations trough ajax calls. You should create a click callback for `table-edit` and `table-delete`.

Comment: I got it to work using row.id and row.destination.  But the hyperlinks end up looking like "myservername/myappname/add.html?id="86".  So I have to remove the quotes around the id somehow.

Comment: any ideas on how I can test the value of row.destination and then create a different hyperlink depending on the value ?

Comment: According the code you show on question, you're adding quotes. Replace `<a href=add.html?id="'+row[0]+'">` by `<a href="add.html?id='+row.id+'">`. In relation to conditional render, use and `if` to decide what link to render

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79565/discussion-between-dot-and-claudio-redi).

Answer (score 6):

take look at my Snippet of Columns part

```
columns: [
    { 'data': 'LastName' },
    { 'data': 'FirstMidName' },
    { 'data': 'EnrollmentDate' },
    {// this is Actions Column 
        mRender: function (data, type, row) {
            var linkEdit = '@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id= -1 })';
            linkEdit = linkEdit.replace("-1", row.ID);

            var linkDetails = '@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id= -1 })';
            linkDetails = linkDetails.replace("-1", row.ID);

            var linkDelete = '@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id= -1 })';
            linkDelete = linkDelete.replace("-1", row.ID);

            return linkDetails + " | " + linkEdit + " | " + linkDelete;
        }
    }
```

and this is snippet from my Json

```
{ID: 1, LastName: "Alexander", FirstMidName: "Carson", EnrollmentDate: "/Date(1126386000000)/",…}
```

Note thate I'm using ASP.Net MVC so `Html.ActionLink` just returning a Link

and the results are 
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this approach helped me with my asp.net core 2 web app. I was Able to add mRender and make use of the linDetails to have a Delete and Edit Link easily. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DataTables has support for Edit and Delete operations.  Delete is fairly simple, like this:

```
$('#id tbody').on('click', function(){
    table
        .row($(this).parents('tr'))
        .remove()
        .draw();
});
```

Check out this example:
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html

Comment: thanks.  I think removing the row from the table on the gui is "easy" but I need to know how to call my back end stuff ... and how to create the options to edit / delete in the first place.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  I've actually only used jQuery DataTables to show data so far.  Now's the chance to look into this further.