# How to populate DataTable using stored procedure in EF database-first

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a stored procedure `GetAllUsers` which returns all the columns from a the table `Users`.

Here is a sample of a the DataTable I want to achieve:

[image]

I'm using Entity Framework (database-first approach).

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUsers]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Users
END
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Create ViewModel/ResourcViewModel instance
        var vm = new ResourceViewModel();

        // Code to fetch data from stored procedure and display to DataTable
    }
```

View model:

```
public class ResourceViewModel
{
    public int UserID { set; get; }
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
}
```

View:

```
<table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Actions</th>

       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Wick</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">iew Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Panther</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">View Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Once I have displayed the list of users into the DataTable. I also want to know how to bind the `UserID` to my `View Details` button.

Comment: `select * from users` doesn't need a stored procedure don't you think ?

Comment: I'm planning to add a variable soon to filter out a specific `UserID`.

Comment: `select * from Users where id=myvariable` ?!!

Comment: Yes. I just want to know how to fetch data from SP to a DataTable first. If you could provide a suggestion that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems to be a little off. With MVC the ideal approach is to return a model to the page, which contains what your after so

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
      public List<ResourceViewModel> Resources { get; set; } 
}
```

Then your view should be more like.

```
@model IndexViewModel
<table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Actions</th>

       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
@foreach(var resource in Model.Resources)
{

    <tr>
        <td>@resource.FirstName</td>
        <td>@resource.LastName</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">View Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Panther</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">View Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

}
</tbody>
</table>
```

So your controller action should be more like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Create ViewModel/ResourcViewModel instance
    var vm = new IndexViewModel();

    // Code to fetch data from stored procedure and display to DataTable
    vm.Resources = new List<ResourceViewModel>();

    foreach(var user in GetAllUsers())
    {

        Resources.Add(new ResourceViewModel(){
            FirstName = user .FirstName,
            LastName = user .LastName,
            UserId = user .UserId
        });
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Obviously this is just so pseudo code, and you will need to correctly call your stored procedure. Alternative to the stored procedure though would be using a Repository pattern, with a Query syntax that will allow you to pass through a lamda where clause through.

Comment: Huge help. I can't seem to make the `.each` appear after the calling the stored procedure. I have the `sp_GetAllUsers_Result` and I can also call the `sp_GetAllUsers`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Apologies, .each is a extension I have in my framework. Just use a standard foreach loop, i'll ammend the answer

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - [In table form controls](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html) to implement custom action button in each row or conditionally.

Define Datatables column layout and customize it according to you need.

**Example:**

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        columns: [
            { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                // Combine the first and last names into a single table field
                return data.first_name+' '+data.last_name;
            } },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "extn" },
            { data: "start_date" },
            { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) },
            {
                data: null,
                className: "center",
                defaultContent: '<a href="" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
            }
        ]
    } );
```

**References:**
[jquery dataTables - how to add an edit and delete option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627026/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-an-edit-and-delete-option)